# Prevent specific widget's rotation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rotation, landscape, portrait

Is it possible to prevent a specific widget from rotating?
I'm making an app that switches a portrait screen mode to a landscape screen mode when I turn my device.
But The QR scanner package I use has an issue with the rotation. So, I would like to prevent only the QR scanner widget from rotating. Is it possible in flutter? hopefully, without external package

Comment: That seems to be an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the issue the package has with switching modes?

Comment: Thanx nvoigt. The image of the camera screen rotates in a strange way on landscape mode. sorry It's kind of hard to explain without image 

[https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/discussions/17](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/discussions/17)